# retrieve only i/o wait times from top

Tags: performance, bash, io

I would like to run a shell script iff. the time spent waiting for i/o devices exceeds a certain threshhold, say 70%, as defined by top. I intend to run a check on this every n interval, say every 1 minute or every 5 minutes, by cron. Despite reading the manual for top, I could not find how to get it to display only the %wa and then quit. Any suggestions?
Thanks!

This is what I have tried so far:

```
WA=$(top -n1 |awk -F, 'NR==3 {print $5}')
tr -d "[:alpha:]" <<< $W
```

yields

```
[[39;49([ 13.9%([[39;49
```

while

```
grep -o "[0-9]"<<<"$WA"
```

yields

```
3
9
4
9
1
3
9
3
9
4
```

None of these is suitable for input into a if -gt; fi conditional statement - and I just can't work out what is going on here!

Comment: No. I now have the problem where the first reading from top is *always* 14.9%. This is because when I run top, it always reads 14.9% in its first interval before climbing to whatever expected range of values I had thought it would be. Since I want to run a script when wait times are high, this doesn't help me.

Comment: On my home machine, top always returns 1.3% for wa in its first interval so presumably this is machine-specific. Not sure what to do about this now. Perhaps take a load average over many intervals some how?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem here is that the output contains few escape sequences which are used for colouring . This causes the issue. One way to resolve is to use `-b` option.

```
$ top -bn2 |awk -F, 'NF==8 {print $5}'|tail -n1|tr -d '[[:alpha:]] '
3.8
```

Here `-b` option will cause `top` to run in batch mode and thus the special escape sequences will not be outputted.

To remove the word `wa` you can use `tr -d '[[:alpha:]] '` which removes any alphabetical characters in the output.

Hope this resolved the problem.

Comment: Thank you, this is the most elegant solution for the updated problem. However, top always returns 14.9% for %wa in its first interval. On my home machine, it always returns 1.3% in its first interval, regardless of whatever else each machine is doing. Since I need to run a script when wait times are high, I'm not currently able to solve my problem..

Comment: Generally top, sar and other utilities provide the cumulative value on their first output. And subsequent outputs will have the current values. I have updated the command so that the value from the second output will be printed.

Comment: One more thing to add, in case if you need to get the average for a specified time interval, like 10 seconds, 1 minute, etc.. then you use `-d` option, like `top -bn2 -d10`. This will output the io-waits that happened during that 10 seconds interval.

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to print `%wa` from top command you can use the following command:

```
top -n1 |awk -F, 'NR==3 {print $5}'
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

This would remove the space as well as `%wa` in the top output

```
 top -n1 |awk -F, ' NR==3 { gsub(/ /, "", $5); gsub (/%.*/,"",$5); print $5}'
```

Explanation:

`gsub(/ /, "", $5)` removes the space from the fifth field which is `%wa` and

`gsub (/%.*/,"",$5)` removes the all the characters after `%`